# Centering shifts last two images in figure?

Tags: graphics, floats

When I add a `\centering` command to a figure with multiple images, it seems to shift the images of the last line a little bit to the right. Can anyone explain why that is? It always seems to affect the last row of images no matter the number of images used.

[image: strange shifting effects]

This is the code I used: (As an image, I used the [tikz/pgf manual](http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf).)

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering %without this line everything is aligned nicely
\foreach \i in {1,...,6}{
\includegraphics[trim=0cm 12cm 0cm 12cm,clip,width=0.48\textwidth]{pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: most likely you want a `%` after the final `}` ending the foreach

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That does indeed make a difference! Can you explain why that is? Also please consider adding this as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `%` after the final `}` ending the `\foreach`.

You are setting all the images as a single paragraph so using X for an image and ␣ for a space your paragraph is

```
␣{x␣x␣x␣x␣x␣x␣}␣
```

as you start in vertical mode the leading ␣ is dropped but when TeX gets to the end of a paragraph it does an implicit `\unskip` to remove a space (usually from the end of the last line) but it only removes *one* space.

So your last line ends in a non dropped space.

With ragged setting then the space will not be noticable unless the x␣x takes up the entire line in which case your paragraph would get one extra spurious line at the end with just a ␣ and the `\parfillskip` (so it will look like vertical space, but with centred setting you centre x␣x␣ instead of x␣x and so the effective width is greater and the first x moves to the left by half the width of a word space.